# BadRequest. The provided workflow action input is not valid. While creating blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am reading the data from one blob storage lot of excel files (in For loop). out of 450 files 2 to 3 CSV files not creating in blob storage.

What is the reason for this? Same file it is processing next day. We are getting the below error.

BadRequest. The provided workflow action input is not valid.

[image]

It is showing the file in blob storage lease storage is Expired like below.

[image]

Thank you
Venu.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the complete error message?
How are the Logic App , Workflows or API connections deployed? Do you see any error on the overview page of the Logic App?

Sometime NVA(Gateway Server) will be  blocking the traffic to Azure services to save the workflows in Standard Logic App, (network  may be blocked on the firewall to connect to Azure Connector endpoints.)please cross verify

Let me answer your expired part. Once a lease has expired, the lease ID is maintained by the Blob service until the blob is modified or leased again. A client may attempt to renew or release their lease using their expired lease ID and know that if the operation is successful, the blob has not been changed since the lease ID was last valid.

If the client attempts to renew or release a lease with their previous lease ID and the request fails, the client then knows that the blob was modified or leased again since their lease was last active. The client must then acquire a new lease on the blob.

If a lease expires rather than being explicitly released, a client may need to wait up to one minute before a new lease can be acquired for the blob. However, the client can renew the lease with their lease ID immediately if the blob has not been modified.

Note that a lease cannot be granted for a blob snapshot, since snapshots are read-only. Requesting a lease against a snapshot results in status code 400 (Bad Request).

The blob's Last-Modified-Time property is not updated by calls to Lease Blob.

The following tables show outcomes of actions on blobs with leases in various lease states. Letters (A), (B), and (C) represent lease IDs, and (X) represents a lease ID generated by the Blob service.

[image]

[image]